# angular get scope property from parents

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Imagine scope `A` has property called `isConfirmed`. Scope `B` is child of `A` and `C` is a child of `B` and on...

A directive controller at level 4 for example.

```
A
|- B
   |- C
      |- D (directive scope)
```

**How can I get the value of `isConfirmed` from my directive's controller?**
I'm avoid of using `$parent` (like `myScope.$parent.$parent.$parent.isConfirmed`!!)

is there any method like `$scope.getValue('isConfirmed')` or ...?

Comment: Can that property be shared through a service/factory?

Comment: If at some level scope is isolated - pass there value, otherwise D.isConfirmed will work.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're trying to do. As @AlekseySolovey has noted, a service would be the best bet. If you don't mind going full nasty, however, you can also use a $broadcast to show the value to the parent

Comment: @DimitrisCSD my directive does validation based on a value in parent scope. the problem is, my directive can't access the value in the parent. it's always `undefined`.

Comment: I understand that. I just suggesting broadcasting it from the parent. Or even simpler (even though as I noted, the cleanest thing would be a service), put the value on $rootScope so that everything can see it.